# How to click 2 screen regions at once and how to click without moving pointer in autohotkey

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

So how to click 2 screen regions at the same time or very fast one after another by using a single hotkey. The intent is to cover clicking on an object that can appear in 2 random areas of the screen by using a single key.

As an example I have tried using

`a::click 735, 626 send, 750, 204 send,` but it creates a loop for a few seconds, where the mouse is unresponsive and hovers in those areas, and using 2 separate hotkeys takes more time than i would wish.

I would also like to know if it is possible to issue a click command via a hotkey but not move the mouse pointer at all. I would like to set a hotkey that pressed will issue a left click command on a determined area of the screen but not move the mouse pointer in order to do so.

Comment: Please elaborate on the context of your problem. What are you intending to achieve? What kind of programs/windows are you working with? Also, please format your question. There is a `{}` button to highlight code. And remove the `pointers` tag, this has nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: Your code is anything but valid. 1. `then` doesn't exist in AHK. 2. `Send` can only take one parameter. (or do you want to send "750, 204" ?) 3. `Send` can't be called without a parameter 4. Multiple statements can't be put into one line. And so on... Did you even try to execute that code?

Comment: I used it without "then" (edited now) and it worked in the way i described it. Only been working with AHK since yesterday and i scraped up what i read in help, but not doing a good job as you can see, also didn't find anywhere the questions i asked here...

Comment: That would fix one of the four syntax errors. Anyway, since your information is very vague, I can only suggest, you inspect the "appearing object's" underlying window (class/title/PID). If the point in time when the window appears is also random, you can use [ShellHook](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/32628-tool-shellhook-messages/) to detect the window upon its creation.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to take a look at the [help docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/) or [FAQ](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm) again as well as some [other examples](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) to understand basic syntax. It is only one command per line.  Here is an example of code that will get you going.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0  ; Sets default mouse speed to maximum

a::
    MouseGetPos, X, Y   ; Stores current mouse position
    Click 735, 626
    Click 735, 500
    MouseMove, % X, % Y ; Moves mouse back to original position
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second question about issuing a click command without using the pointer, I suggest you look at the ControlClick documentation here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm